# VLOOKUP unable to function properly

Tags: excel

I've got two workbooks as follow:

workbook A:

```
name     sex
jay       M
katy      F
```

workbook B:

```
name     age
jay       25
katy      26
```

and I would like to use VLOOKUP to bring back the age values to workbook A. however, the result is:

```
name     sex    age
jay       M      #N/A
katy      F      #N/A
```

It really makes me annoying cause the name value is exactly identical but VLOOKUP couldn't find the age value.

Comment: Please show us the formula you are using.

Comment: did u check for blank spaces that might be in the names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of VLookup, try [index](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) & [match](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a):

> MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])
>
> INDEX(array, row_num, [column_num])

```
=INDEX(Sheet2.B2:B3,MATCH(A2:A3,Sheet2.A2:A3,0))
```

If you must use [VLookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1), then check that you have the formulas set up as such:

> VLOOKUP(value, table, col_index, [range_lookup])

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2.A2:B3,2)
```

If you still have an issue, try checking the value [type](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TYPE-function-45b4e688-4bc3-48b3-a105-ffa892995899) you have in your excel sheet.
You might have a proceeding astrophe `, or a text type instead of a number type:

```
=TYPE(B2)
1
```

1 indicates a number type.